# Using seterror method for validating edittext in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two edittexts for username and password ,I use the seterror method to show an error when both of them are empty.The problem is when the error message pops up in the second field(the password field) , part of the message is missing.This bug is there only on older devices.How do i ensure that the error does not happen in older devices.

My code:

```
public class SignInPage extends Activity {

    EditText txtusername,txtpassword;
    Button btnlogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signinpage);
        txtusername=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
        txtpassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
        btnlogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(txtusername.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    txtusername.setError("Username is mandatory");
                    txtusername.requestFocus();
                }
                if(txtpassword.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    txtpassword.setError("Password is mandatory");
                    txtpassword.requestFocus();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Checking with server",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you say that the error is shown partially is because it gets out of the screen?, or just it does not appear completely

Comment: can you please post the screen shot ?

Comment: You can see error message on both Edittext. But your first Edittext will show you error message and when you click on password edittext error it also show you message.

Comment: yes, but when i click on the second field , the soft keyboard pops up so the error message is shown on the top of the edittext,but it is shown partially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you

```
fname = FirstName.getText().toString().trim();
if(fname.isEmpty()) //&& fname.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
             {
                 FirstName.requestFocus();
                 FirstName.setError(Html.fromHtml("<font color='red'>Please enter the First name</font>")); 
             }
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        { }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
        { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) 
        {
            if(arg0.toString().isEmpty()) 
            {
                return;
            }

            if (FirstName.getText() == arg0) {
                Validate(FirstName);
FirstName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

public void Validate(EditText et) {     
    et.setError(null);
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is that when the soft keyboard pops up , the error message goes to the top of the edittext and hence it is shown partially.

Comment: @user3852672 can you post the screen shot then I will be able to help you more precisely ... :)

Comment: @user3852672 I am running this validation on my form and it's working perfectly even if the keyboard pops up .so please post the screen shot or code if you can..

Comment: are you using a new device or an old one?